# How to set up indexes so a user can login via email or username in Dynamodb

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to architect a DynamoDB solution that will have users. I am opting for a single table design and there are a bunch of relationships that I will need to accommodate but those are probably inconsequential to this question. This table will accommodate user authentication and users will log in using the credentials that are stored in this database.

I obviously have to use index overloading to achieve this. The PK will hold values like USER_ID_XXXX, NOTE_ID_XXXX and the sort key will vary contextually depending on the contents of the PK.

A user will have attributes email, username and password.

I was thinking of doing something like the following, where 'data' is an attribute that all records will have and will vary according to context derived from the PK/SK combination:

PK: USER_ID_XXXX, SK: USERNAME, DATA: james, password: abc
PK: USER_ID_XXXX, SK: EMAIL, DATA: james@test.com, password: abc

And then every time the password is changed for USER_ID_XXXX update it on the records where the SK = USERNAME or EMAIL.

The problem is I don't know how to create a GSI that will only include records where SK = USERNAME or EMAIL, so my GSI will be bloated unnecessarily with every record.

I thought instead I could use attribute USERNAME instead of DATA and create a GSI for that. Usernames cannot have '@'s in them so there will be no conflicts between usernames and emails, but then I'm unsure of what to use for the SK in this instance.

What is the better solution here? And if the answer is the second, how would I set up the SK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a table with

- Primary Key: Username
- GSI: Email

Any arbitrary data can be stored as non-key attributes. Ex.

```
{
  username: "james", // Primary key
  email: "james@domain.com", // GSI
  password: "randomhashedpassword",
  ... other non-key attributes
}
```

When you receive the request with email/username, you can either query with username or email and then match the password retrieved from the input password.

Note that GSI do not guarantee uniqueness. So you need to also avoid cases where an email is already being used during registration. Ex. a registration with `james111/james@test.com` should fail if someone has already registered with `james/james@test.com` as the email is already used. This will ensure that when you query on GSI, you are guaranteed to get a single value.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you got an answer to your question since it was +3 years ago.

I'll post my answer anyway for future users.

I would suggest creating a number of tables, First, create a users table. this table will hold all your user information and all you need is a partition key based on the `user_id`.

Now let's say you need to look up a user based on email, username, and phone number too.

Create a table for each lookup method that will use the email as a partition key and the value will be the user_id.

So when looking up a user with `email` you'll make a select query to the `users-email` table, fetch the `user_id` and get the user record.
The same will be fetching the user with a phone or any other method needed.

Hope that helps.